# What may be the cause of the laptop screen discoloration on Lenovo Y530?

Tags: display, hardware-failure

I have this discolouration with a red tint, is the cable or the screen that's faulty and need to be replaced ?
[image]

Comment: 1. Update BIOS, Chipset and Video drivers.  2. Get the Lenovo Update App (Lenovo web site) and run that to ensure all drivers are update.  3. Same site get Lenovo Diagnostics and run that to see if there are hardware errors.

Comment: It looks like physical damage to the LCD itself; try plugging in a monitor to see if that looks OK.

Comment: No idea how this could ever be the fault of drivers or BIOS ...

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the screen.
Note there are two versions of this screen one HD and one FHD. Make sure you pick the one that was installed before.